# How to remove space between bootstrap divs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have three `div`s like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="header">
        Welcome
    </div>
    <div class="navbar">
        Menu
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        Website content
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, the first `div` `class="container-fluid"` is stretched on all browser window. The next `class="header` has `padding`/`margin` of some pixels from his parent element. Now I´d like this `div` to stretch all browser window out. But I also don´t want next `class="menu"` or `class="content"` to be stretched out.

How may I solve this?

Comment: Its a `div` so it will occupy full-width of the screen, what exactly are you seeking?

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay No, it won´t. I´m using Bootstrap as it says in the topic!

Comment: then give a little briefing, JSFiddle or img something, its not clear, what exactly you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.container for navbar and content` & `.row for .header` like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/11315/)**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="header col-xs-12 col-sm-12 ">Welcome</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar">Menu</div>
        <div class="content">Website content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This will be the correct answear. Just change "container-fluid" to "row". And all margin/padding disapear. Perfect.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="header">
        Welcome
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
     <div class="navbar">
          Menu
     </div>
     <div class="content">
          Website content
     </div>
 </div>
```

Use `container` class outside menu and content. Hope this will help you.

jsFiddle [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/anilram25/1x5exyub/)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a two-column layout with a full-width header. You tagged Twitter Bootstrap so I'll explain how to use those styles to do what you want.

```
<div class="row container-fluid">
    <div class="header">
        Welcome
    </div>
    <div class="span3 navbar">
        Menu
    </div>
    <div class="span9 content">
        Website content
    </div>
</div>
```

The `row` class is on the element that wraps the columns. `span#` is the class that gives each column its size. So for a 12-unit width, you could assign `span3` to the navbar and `span9` to the content area.

---

Without Bootstrap, this is still relatively simple. You can do this in CSS.

```
.navbar {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
}

.content {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 75%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But it´s not really what i want. I´d like the divs inside container to be on seperate rows... so the width of navbar will be 100% and content 90%. Bootstrap adds margin to each div so the header div inside of container div will not be border to border.. it will be border, 2px air, border. Sorry for bad explain...

Comment: Well don´t hang upp with the classes, i´d just took some now in this example. It´s only "container-fluid" i use.. BT 3